# Key variable is overriding in Stripe Go SDK

Tags: go, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Go SDK to handle payments on my site.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go

**Overview**

My product works on merchant basis. There are multiple merchants and every merchant has its own database. Therefore every merchant has different stripe keys for payment.

I am facing a weird issue.

When we set the secret key in our code to call stripe apis, it got set in `stripe.Key` variable of SDK. Now if this variable is set for one merchant and it may have multiple stripe request on one event like get data then update it.

```
stripe.Key = SECRET KEY
```

Now if another merchant simultaneously initiate another stripe request then in `stripe.Key` variable, the secret key of second merchant is updated.

Due to this, I got following error:

```
{
  "chargeid": "",
  "code": "resource_missing",
  "declinecode": "",
  "docurl": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
  "err": {},
  "httpstatuscode": 404,
  "msg": "No such payment_intent: pi_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "oautherror": "",
  "oautherrordescription": "",
  "param": "intent",
  "paymentintent": null,
  "paymentmethod": null,
  "requestid": "REQ_ID",
  "setupintent": null,
  "source": null,
  "type": "invalid_request_error"
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening in case of simultaneous request. Is there any way within the SDk ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `client.API` to set the API Key per request instead of a global one. Here is an example (see below). You have more detailed explanation on the [GitHub](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go#with-a-client) or in Stripe [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication).

```
import (
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v71"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v71/client"
)

sc := &client.API{}
sc.Init("sk_key", nil)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I will give it a try if it works.